# add unicode link in site map or farsi characters?

Tags: unicode, persian

i have a shop moudle in my site that it cant be inclouded in website sitemap builder , because the sitemap builder doesnt incloude it in site map.
so im making a site map for it separately my self!
there is the main problem! links in main sitemap has perisan characters as you see below:
[سایت مپ الکترورام][1]
but when in copy links from browser for making a handmade site map it will be like:
[سایت مپ فروشگاه الکتروارم][2]
here is the question!, which one is better? unicode or farsi characters? if farsi, how can i copy links with out braking it in unicodes?
 (deleted because i paste samples here):

first form(farsi into some codes!):

```
<url><loc>http://electroeram.ir/shop/product/5/%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-160-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%BE%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D9%87-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B2-15-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-cpd480/</loc><lastmod>2016-10-14</lastmod><priority>0.6</priority></url>
```

second form (farsi in regular character):

```
<url><loc>http://electroeram.ir/main/5-تحویل-محموله-ی-جدید-الکتروارم-از-کانال-پلاست-ایتالیا.html</loc><lastmod>2016-10-16</lastmod><priority>0.6</priority></url>
```

Comment: ‘*unicode or farsi characters? if farsi, how can i copy links with out braking it in unicodes?*’ It seems you don't quite understand what Unicode *is*. What are you *really* asking here?!

Comment: OK maybe i dont know what it is: http://electroeram.ir/main/5-تحویل-محموله-ی-جدید-الکتروارم-از-کانال-پلاست-ایتالیا.html this link has farsi charachters! from standard site map, and this one :http://electroeram.ir/shop/product/5/%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-160-%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%BE%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D9%87-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B2-15-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%BE%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-cpd480/ was a farsi link which turned to this! so which one is ok for site map,if first one,how can i change second one to it?

Comment: What are you asking then?! Perhaps you should read up on Unicode, e.g. [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: I see two links whose URLs both contain Farsi characters. What's the difference?

Comment: well! it seems that pasting link in here ,make both of them look same,please take a look in sitemaps,in one form,link has a loong english code (instead of farsi regular form),in second form it has farsi regular form! first one was a hand made sitemap,second one is automatic generated, which one is correct for site map,and if second one is ok,how can i get regular shape instead of those codes while copy the farsi link

Comment: Paste the code here.

Comment: ok i edited first post now you can see it:)

Comment: That's called *percent encoding* or *URI encoding*.

Comment: ok,thanks for it, now which one is correct for sitemap? the uri encoded one or regular one? if the regular one,how can i avoid copying uri encoded?

Comment: What does the specification say? You avoid copying a percent-encoded URI by… not copying a percent-encoded URI. Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: ok i found my answer , by turning network.standard-url scape in about:config i can avoid it

Answer (score -1):

ok as long as there are many big sites like mihandownload that has url encoded urls in site map, there is no need to change the urls into regular ones for sitemaps.
but if you want it, just use this in fire fox:
tyoe about:config
search for network.standard-url and make the scape one, false